# Getting Hash and Storing in Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, hash

I'm trying to take the hashed value from an object. What I'm basically doing is this:

```
target = $('a[href^="#products"]');
targetHashed = target.hash;
$targetHashed = $(targetHashed);
console.log(targetHashed);
```

I'm putting the reference in "target", then getting the hashing and everything following it with ".hash" then converting the variable that contains the hashed value "targetHashed" to an object so I can do things like getting the offset, etc. Problem is that "targetHashed" is outputting undefined whenever I try to append .hash to it. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You're looking for href starts with `#products`. What do they end with? I'm trying to figure out if you can use href directly or you need to parse it. No question that your code will never work though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value of the href attribute of the selected elements you need to use `attr` so your second line would look something like.

```
targetHashed = target.attr('href');
```

But that only selects the first element, if you want to use all of them then you'll need to loop through that array.